# update multiple elements at once LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to set property on each element from List using LINQ.

for example:

```
var users = from u in context.Users where u.Name == "George" select u;

foreach (User us in users){
   us.MyProp = false;
}
```

Is it possible to make it cleaner ?

Comment: No, neither LINQ nor LINQ to SQL has set-based update capabilities.

Comment: How would you define *cleaner*? Shorter? Less use of constructs including indendtation? Fewer lines of code in your method?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Or you can convert it to ToList() and use ForEach method.

```
users.ToList().ForEach(u => u.MyProp = false);
```

to update more than one properties

```
users.ToList().ForEach(u =>
                      {
                         u.property1 = value1;
                         u.property2 = value2;
                      });
```

Or like this

```
(from u in context.Users where u.Name == "George" select u).ToList()
.ForEach(u => u.MyProp = false);
```

Comment: +1 but this would void the benefits of deferred execution of IEnumerable<T>, but I imagine that this feature would bring an interesting amount of weird behaviors. The objects would be modified only when iterated over (!)

Comment: @Johann Blais: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx is a nice read

Comment: I had this article in mind when I wrote my comment. A very nice read indeed. :)

Comment: There's an error in your *ForEach* statement. `.ForEach({ u =>` should be `.ForEach( u => {`

Comment: Would this approach perform better than to loop every element in a foreach loop and update them individually inside the loop? @Niklas

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own ForEach extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        action(element);
    }

    return source;
}
```

Then your code can be simplified to:

```
context.Users.Where(x => x.Name == "George").ForEach(u => u.MyProp = false);
```

EDIT: You could also yield return each item after the call to action() (no pun intended) to leave the deferred execution untouched.

Comment: wouldn't it be `context.Users.Where(x => x.Name == "George").ForEach(u => u.MyProp = false);`

Comment: @Shiv: that is not correct. `List<T>` has a `ForEach` method, but `IEnumerable<T>` does not.

Comment: @Shiv IEnumerable doesn't, a List<T> has ForEach though so .ToList could be used. Also the only time i've seen it with a ForAll is when it's made parallel

Comment: @Shiv: Can you give a source for your comment? I just checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx and don't seem to find such a method. We infact explicitly created such an extension in our framework!

Comment: @Manatherin, your solution won't work, will it? ForEach is not a method on IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @Manatherin: true! I skipped that part.

Comment: @Shiv i was commenting on the post that suggested adding a extension method on it though

Comment: Yes, List<T> has a ForEach. If you think about it, you would iterate over "all" to do a ForEach so...

Comment: `Users.Where(x => x.Name == "George").ToList().ForEach(u => u.MyProp = false)`
would do the trick

Answer (score 3):

What is *cleaner* is quite subjective. Personally, I find this approach hard to beat for clarity and simplicity:

```
foreach (User us in users.Where(u => u.Name == "George"))
{
   us.MyProp = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in in-memory update, that is the database is not going to be updated then you could use

```
var users = (from u in context.Users where u.Name == "George" select u).ToList();
users.ForEach(u => u.MyProp = "Something");
```

Comment: I don't think IEnumerable contains a ForEach method.

Comment: @Anuraj, missed the .ToList(). I've updated my code to include the query portion so it's clear

Comment: I think you need to remove the var users declaration too. Otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Looks dirty but if asked (just via select), I'll do it this way

```
var users = from u in context.Users where u.Name == "George" 
select new User() 
{
   prop1 = u.prop1,
   prop2 = u.prop2,
   prop3 = true // update like here
};
```

if you wish to use some other C# function, you can also use linq functions and work on IEnumerable type of lists.

```
var users = context.Users.Where(u => u.Name == "George").ToList()
    .Select(p => new User() 
    {
       prop1 = p.prop1,
       prop2 = p.prop2,
       prop3 = ComputeHash(p) // update like here
    });
```

Code above becomes IEnumerable because of the `.ToList()` prior to the `.Select()`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 context.Users.Where(u => u.Name == "George").Select(u => u.MyProp = false);
```

Comment: you can't change the value in the select statement

Comment: @Manatherin: well in theory it can be done, but not like in this answer (and not in a way that would really make sense).