# Update class field in LINQ - is it possible?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, refactoring, anonymous-types

I have 2 tables, and want to get records from 1 table and to "update" one of its fields from another table, and to pass final list of "Payment" objects somewhere. I cannot use anonymouse type, i need to get the list of proper typed objects.

There was a long way.

Got data:

```
var paymentsToShow = from p in paymentsRepository.Payments
                     join r in recordTypeRepository.RecordType
                         on p.RecordType equals r.Reference into p_r
                     where p.Customer == CustomerRef
                     from r in p_r.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                         Payment = p,
                         RecordType = r
                     };
var objList = paymentsToShow.ToList();
```

Change required field (basically, **Payment.RecordTypeName** is empty):

```
foreach (var obj in objList)
{
    obj.Payment.RecordTypeName = obj.RecordType.Name;
}
```

Got list with correct type:

```
var paymentsList = from o in objList
                   select o.Payment;
```

Is there any way to get code shorter, to make required field update in the query or something else? I dont know where to look for.
I cannot change database.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165410/update-multiple-elements-at-once-linq/5165474#comment-5801169

Comment: You say you can't use anonymous types, but you are using them already...

Comment: @Daniel , finally i got **paymentsList**, which is not anonymous. and pass it to another function. I cannot pass anonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var paymentsToShow = (from p in paymentsRepository.Payments
                      join r in recordTypeRepository.RecordType
                          on p.RecordType equals r.Reference into p_r
                      where p.Customer == CustomerRef
                      from r in p_r.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new
                      {
                          Payment = p,
                          RecordType = r
                      }).Select(x =>
                                {
                                    x.Payment.RecordTypeName = x.RecordType.Name;
                                    return x.Payment;
                                });
```

This will result in an `IEnumerable<Payment>`, so no anonymous type used.