# Update multiple columns in linq using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, lambda

I want to update record in `DataTable` using `Linq` and `Lambda Expression`. I can update one column as below

```
dtProduct.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Field<long>("ProductId") == Convert.ToInt64(id)).First().SetField("Qty", qty);
```

cant understand how to update others :(. I am ended up with writing update several times for each column.

Comment: You could do it in a select but you really shouldn't, a good rule of thumb is a query should not cause side effects. Retrieve the records you want using Linq then iterate over then in a foreach and set the values you wish.

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165410/update-multiple-elements-at-once-linq/5165555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I ended up with writing update several times for each column.

Your code consists of two parts:

- Locating the instance, and
- Setting its field.

You can reuse the results of locating the instance by introducing a variable:

```
var inst = dtProduct.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Field<long>("ProductId") == Convert.ToInt64(id)).First();
```

Now you can call `SetField` on it multiple times:

```
inst.SetField("Qty", qty);
inst.SetField("Price", price);
inst.SetField("Weight", weight);
```

Comment: nice answer, can't I do this in single line?

Comment: @Imad Unfortunately, no, because `SetField` returns `void`. You could introduce your own `SetFieldAndChain` method that returns the original `DataRow`, but that would probably be slightly less readable.

Comment: That a great idea. I will surely implement :)

Answer (score -1):

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows1 = 
             dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .ToList()
            .FindAll(x => (x.Cells["Select"].Value=1).ToString().Equals("1")?true:false);
```

We are trying to find something and in disguise we are setting a value to all rows.

```
x.Cells["Select"].Value=1
```

we are least bothered about what output it gives, but our aim of setting a value to each column "Select" is succeeded.