# Merge duplicate data with condition in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Members:

```
 List<Members> MyMembers= new List<Members>();
```

Members class:

```
public class Members
{
     public int IdKey;
     public string name;
     public string relationBegin;
     public string relationEnd;
     public bool isOriginal;
 }
```

I need to merge duplicate IdKey into one.
This can be done using something like:

```
MyMembers=MyMembers.GroupBy(x => x.IdKey )
      .Select(g => new Members{ IdKey = g.Key })
      .ToList();
```

Here is where the fun begins.

The condiation is that if we detect duplicate IdKey It need to preserve the one that has isOriginal=true (if both isOriginal=false, we leave isOriginal to false but update dates begin and end as explained in next statment)

Furthermore,
We need preserve the lowest relationBegin and highest relationEnd from the two duplicates, Sometimes relationBegin or relationEnd  could be Null or empty.

Example:
Row1:

- IsOriginal=true
- relationBegin = 1/1/2017
- relationEnd = 10/10/2018

Example: 
Row2:

- IsOriginal=false
- relationBegin = 1/1/2015
- relationEnd = NULL

Result would be:

- IsOriginal= true
- relationBegin=1/1/2015
- relationEnd 10/10/2018

Comment: I think you're better off not using LINQ, in my opinion.  Once you get beyond a fairly-simple logic, it just becomes too cluttered and is easier to read through if it's separate statements.

Comment: And what happens iif you have 3 entries with the same key?

Comment: @DavidG Same logic, Lowest `relationEnd`, Highest `relationBegin` and if any says IsOriginal = true we need to state that also.

Comment: foreach will be much cleaner here

Comment: @Amit Yes, i might try to simplify it than using LINQ. also like rory.ap mentioned.

Comment: @Dror if you are just trying things out, yes you must do it with linq, but in product (especially when you are working in a team) clean code is also an important factor to be considered!

Comment: Use for each in linq to update your list of members. Here is a linq to possible related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165410/update-multiple-elements-at-once-linq/5165555?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if your `Member` class would have `DateTime` instead of string Date time.

if you need them in string, you can have property like below.

```
public class Members
{
    public int IdKey;
    public string name;
    public string relationBegin;
    public string relationEnd;
    public bool isOriginal;

    public DateTime RelationBeginDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.ParseExact(relationBegin, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }
    public DateTime RelationEndDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.ParseExact(relationEnd, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
    }

    public Members(int IdKey, string name, string relationBegin, string relationEnd, bool isOriginal)
    {
        //assign paramters to proper properties
    }
}
```

and your desired `linq` will be something like below.

```
    MyMembers = MyMembers.GroupBy(x => x.IdKey)
      .Select(g => new Members(
         g.Key, //Id will be same as you shown in question
         g.FirstOrDefault().name, //assuming name will be same in all
         g.Select(x => x.RelationBeginDate).Min().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"), //Min begin date
         g.Select(x => x.RelationEndDate).Max().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"),   //Max end date
         g.Any( x => x.isOriginal))).ToList();      //if isOriginal = true found
```

Comment: Full disclosure, I ended up catching the duplicates **before** they happen instead of dealing with them **after** they happen. having said that, this LINQ is awesome.

Comment: @Dror I am glad that this answer helped you